# Aligning items to the right in a ListView in Qt6 QML

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt6

I would like to have a `ListView` that fit to the width of its largest item.
I also want the items to be right-aligned in the `ListView`.

So, as a naive approach, I've done that:

```
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    id: window

    ListView {
        id: view
        anchors.left: window.left
        height: contentHeight
        spacing: 5

        // making the list the width of its content
        width: contentItem.childrenRect.width

        model: ["A", "bb", "CCcc", "DDddDD"]

        delegate: Text {
            text: modelData
            font.pointSize: 24

            // aligning the item to the right
            anchors.right: parent.right
        }
    }
}
```

Visually, it is working. However I am getting this warning:

```
QML ListView: Binding loop detected for property "width"
```

So, this approach doesn't seem to be the correct way of achieving what I want.
I've tried other things too, like setting the `implicitWidth` (with the same result), or setting `contentWidth` instead or `horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight` in the `Text` but with a wrong visual result.

So, I'm wondering, is there a proper way to align items to the right in a `ListView`, or do I have to live with that warning?

Comment: The binding loop is due to the delegate items getting their width from the ListView, but your ListView gets its width from its children (the delegates). I'm actually surprised that works at all.

Comment: The normal way to right-justify text is to use the horizontalAlignment property, as you mentioned. Can you describe what actually is wrong when you use that?

Comment: @JarMan the delegates don't get their width from the ListView there.

Comment: @JarMan It doesn't work with `horizontalAlignment` because the items don't have the width of the ListView, but their implicit width. So they are visually left aligned.

Comment: @JarMan also, the binding loop comes from the two lines I've commented. If I remove either one the binding loop is not there.

Comment: @Grecko, You're right. I realized that afterwards. For some reason I was thinking they automatically get sized to the ListView, but that's definitely not true.

Comment: If we consider that the size of items and `childrenRect` would vary while scrolling the `ListView`, it's not recommended to even use the `childrenRect.width` for initializing the `ListView`'s `width`. However, if you know that all of your items would always be visible and instantiated, you can use a combination of `Grid` or `ColumnLayout` and `Repeater`, which the container itself also supports aligning inner Items.

Answer (score 0):

The Binding loop is very real, because:

- ListView.width depends on ListView.contentItem.childrenRect
- ListView.contentItem.childrenRect depends on ListView.width

Hypothetically, consider we had introduced `wordWrap: Text.Wrap`.

```
ListView {
    width: contentItem.childrenRect.width
    delegate: Text {
        text: modelData
        wordWrap: Text.Wrap
    }
}
```

The `Text.width` directly influences the `Text.height`. So, therefore the `ListView.width` can influence the `ListView.contentItem.childrenRect.height`. However, at the same time, `ListView.contentItem.childrenRect.width` is having an influence on `ListView.width`.

The compiler detects this and warns you of it. You can disable/remove the property binding and, in it's place, use `Component.onCompleted` and/or `contentItem.childrenRectChanged` events to invoke a `setWidth()` function.

```
    ListView {
        id: view
        anchors.left: window.left
        height: contentHeight
        spacing: 5

        // making the list the width of its content
        //width: contentItem.childrenRect.width

        model: ["A", "bb", "CCcc", "DDddDD"]

        delegate: Text {
            text: modelData
            font.pointSize: 24

            // aligning the item to the right
            anchors.right: parent.right
        }
        contentItem.onChildrenRectChanged: Qt.callLater(setWidth)
        function setWidth() {
            width = 0;
            width = contentItem.childrenRect.width
        }
        Component.onCompleted: setWidth()
        footer: Button {
            width: ListView.view.width
            text: "Change Me"
            onClicked: view.model = ["X", "yy", "ZZZ", "WWWWWWWWWWW".slice(0,Math.floor(Math.random()*10)) ]
        }
    }
```

You can [Try the above snippet online](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADpHichVNLT9wwEL7nV4xySipktlW5BPXQJodWAqlLUUGLOBhnklg49sqZZQto/3vHWTaPLVJ9sOdlzzffjHW7dp5gScuNVo+Rnqkid5a8M130U9YIrxHwutAd/da4fVPD0mUGT2waDNKqxvlOGKwog622pdv2yhDRoK4b9inOgJa+9+rg7dZSaVtncBYNttNTaOUjW4EaBMMoemGrS2rAVaCpO7w2udO7hzQ/CFuhGm1Kj/YKFYnePyZpXYkmg7v4a3wC8cND2PNcqXAWRVkWRXw/RnMs1pIwg2v8QxNCwiI2ZfsHC0ly5qsYjlg7bemXfuHrnz5HMz/XKo2u7aFazbiBXC/7GVNTtv2e0rXk4kjM43aDNKXC2XxCRt5IWyP3cklCSWMuuDSfdEg3gaR0eKHaWEXaWTi4kvSo9n1TvsDi/F3zf7rxL+bc8VzaUBUjZtkgBZxj/hGbcww6g28bIkb4DqxsmGARZvYo59i5eE8HXGI88zICw38D32Ze9B3mou7i2zAlz89hX61W4bgZVyw6vobJ4uRSUiMq45xPetFL/h5tkn74uEhTuD8qfxft/gJd8wrG)